# What is wrong with my sparse matrix-multiple vectors (SpMM) product function for CSR?

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, blas, intel-mkl

I have the following code for the sparse matrix-vector (SpMV) product in C assuming a CSR storage format:

```c
void dcsrmv(SparseMatrixCSR *A, double *x, double *y) {
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) {
    double sum = 0.;
    for (int jj=A->row_start[i]; jj<A->row_start[i+1]; jj++) {
      sum += A->val[jj] * x[A->col_idx[jj]];
    }
    y[i] = sum;
  }
}
```

when I run this function 100 times with the array `ecology1` from the SuiteSparse Matrix Collection, the average runtime is 5.9 ms, whereas if I run MKL's `mkl_sparse_d_mv` function with the same matrix, I get an average runtime of 8.4 ms.

Now, I would like to have a sparse matrix-multiple vectors (SpMM) product function for the same storage format, which I coded following 3 approaches:

```c
void dcsrmm0(SparseMatrixCSR *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
    double *x = X + vec * A->n;
    double *y = Y + vec * A->m;
    for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) {
      double sum = 0.;
      for (int jj=A->row_start[i]; jj<A->row_start[i+1]; jj++) {
        sum += A->val[jj] * x[A->col_idx[jj]];
      }
      y[i] = sum;
    }
  }
}
```

```c
void dcsrmm1(SparseMatrixCSR *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) {
    for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
      double sum = 0.;
      double *x = X + vec * A->n;
      double *y = Y + vec * A->m;
      for (int jj=A->row_start[i]; jj<A->row_start[i+1]; jj++) {
        sum += A->val[jj] * x[A->col_idx[jj]];
      }
      y[i] = sum;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```c
void dcsrmm2(SparseMatrixCSR *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  double *x[nvec], *y[nvec];
  for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) x[vec] = X + vec * A->n;
  for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) y[vec] = Y + vec * A->m;
  double sum[nvec];
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) {
    for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) sum[vec] = 0.;
    for (int jj=A->row_start[i]; jj<A->row_start[i+1]; jj++) {
      for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
        sum[vec] += A->val[jj] * x[vec][A->col_idx[jj]];
      }
    }
    for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) y[vec][i] = sum[vec];
  }
}
```

where `X` and `Y` are stored by column.

Then I benchmark these functions with `nvec=10`. In which case `dcsrmm0` takes 49.8 ms on average, `dcsrmm1` takes 38.3 ms on average, and `dcsrmm2` takes 34.8 ms on average, while `mkl_sparse_d_mm` takes only 26.7 ms.

So my question is, why is it that my implementation of `dcsrmv` does better than `mkl_sparse_d_mv`, but my `dcsrmm0-2` functions lag so much behind `mkl_sparse_d_mm`? What can I do to improve these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following alternative gives me the best results:

```c
void dcsrmm2_improved(SparseMatrixCSR *A, double *X, double *Y, int nvec) {
  double *x[nvec];
  for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) x[vec] = X + vec * A->n;
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) {
    double *y = Y + i;
    for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) y[vec * A->m] = 0.;
    for (int jj=A->row_start[i]; jj<A->row_start[i+1]; jj++) {
      double val = A->val[jj];
      int j = A->col_idx[jj];
      for (int vec=0; vec<nvec; vec++) {
        y[vec * A->m] += val * x[vec][j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I run this function 100 times with the array `ecology1` from the SuiteSparse Matrix Collection, I get an average runtime of 27.6 ms, which is reasonably close to the 26.7 ms obtained with `mkl_sparse_d_mm` using the CSR format.

If anyone knows how to get further improvements, let me know.